# Unable to load Keras model in Keras 2.4.3 (with Tensorflow 2.3.0) that was saved in Keras 2.1.0 (with Tensorflow 1.3.0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, batch-normalization

I'm implementing a Keras model with a custom batch-renormalization layer, which has 4 weights (beta, gamma, running_mean, and running_std) and 3 state variables (r_max, d_max, and t):

```
    self.gamma = self.add_weight(shape = shape, #NK - shape = shape
                                 initializer=self.gamma_init,
                                 regularizer=self.gamma_regularizer,
                                 name='{}_gamma'.format(self.name))
    self.beta = self.add_weight(shape = shape, #NK - shape = shape
                                initializer=self.beta_init,
                                regularizer=self.beta_regularizer,
                                name='{}_beta'.format(self.name))
    self.running_mean = self.add_weight(shape = shape, #NK - shape = shape
                                        initializer='zero',
                                        name='{}_running_mean'.format(self.name),
                                        trainable=False)
    # Note: running_std actually holds the running variance, not the running std.
    self.running_std = self.add_weight(shape = shape, initializer='one',
                                       name='{}_running_std'.format(self.name),
                                       trainable=False)
    self.r_max = K.variable(np.ones((1,)), name='{}_r_max'.format(self.name))

    self.d_max = K.variable(np.zeros((1,)), name='{}_d_max'.format(self.name))

    self.t = K.variable(np.zeros((1,)), name='{}_t'.format(self.name))
```

When I checkpoint the model, only gamma, beta, running_mean, and running_std are saved (as expected), but when I try to load the model, I get this error:

```
Layer #1 (named "batch_renormalization_1" in the current model) was found to correspond to layer batch_renormalization_1 in the save file. However the new layer batch_renormalization_1 expects 7 weights, but the saved weights have 4 elements.
```

So it looks like the model is expecting all 7 weights to be part of the saved file, even though some of them are state variables.

Any insights as to how to get around this?

**EDIT:** I realize that the problem was that the model was trained and saved on Keras 2.1.0 (with Tensorflow 1.3.0 backend), and I only get the error when loading the model using Keras 2.4.3 (with Tensorflow 2.3.0 backend). I am able to load the model using Keras to 2.1.0.

So the real question is - what changed in Keras/Tensorflow, and is there a way to load older models without receiving this error?

Answer (score 0):

You cant not load the model this way because keras.models.load_model will load the configuration that has been defined, not something has been self_customed.

To overcome this, you should reload the model architecture and try to load_weights from that instead:

```
model = YourModelDeclaration()
model.load_weights("checkpoint/h5file")
```

I have the same problem when I self custom BatchNormalize, so I would be pretty sure this is the only way to load it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but load_weights doesn't work either. After some digging, I found that the error is actually caused by saving and then attempting to load on different versions of Keras/Tensorflow. So real question is whether there's a way to load models saved in older versions of Keras without running into this error.

Comment: Obviously, you should not save weights only in a different version and then load it in a newer one. But it is strange that even saving the whole model cant save you moving back and forth :D

Comment: It seems like this could be a common issue. In this case, I'm attempting to use a model created by someone else, and they didn't provide detailed information on what version of Tensorflow/Keras they used. So it took a bit of guess-and-check to get things working. It seems to me like model loading should work across versions, or sharing models will be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

In Keras, there's two ways to save the state of your model.

You can call the `model.save()` and `model.save_weights()` functions.

`model.save()` saves the entire model, including the weights and gradients. In your case, the 4 weights and 3 state variables will all be saved by this method. You can simply use the `load_model("path.h5")` method to get your model back.

The `model.save_weights()` function only saves the weights of the model and does not save the structure at all. The important thing to note here is that the **Keras checkpoint callback uses the `model.save_weights()` method under the hood**. If you wish to use the checkpoint weights, you must instantiate your model structure `model = customModel()` and then load the weights into it `model.load_weights("checkpoint.h5")`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but load_weights doesn't work either. After some digging, I found that the error is actually caused by saving and then attempting to load on different versions of Keras/Tensorflow. So real question is whether there's a way to load models saved in older versions of Keras without running into this error.

Comment: From my understanding, you cannot move between Keras/tf versions when saving and loading models.